# Looking for a windows application to parse and filter large volumes of text

Tags: untagged

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a windows application to parse and filter large volumes of text](https://serverfault.com/questions/425441/looking-for-a-windows-application-to-parse-and-filter-large-volumes-of-text)

Looking for a lean windows application that will let me search through very large log files efficiently for specific error keywords, ideally with the ability to filter such keywords.

Comment: Please don't open or post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want something that can do regular expressions - but I agree that this is a superuser/serverfault question...

EDIT - mainly I would install cygwin and use tools like grep.  The *nix command line is remarkably powerful for such activities - particularly when you can script them together - or use a scripting language like python or perl.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to do this once, you could probably get away with grep and regular expressions.

You don't mention the operating system, so that makes things a bit more difficult to answer very precisely.

Grep is present on Unix/Linux, but you could also get it on Windows with Cygwin. Or there is a lot of other tools that support regular expressions for splitting and recombining things, starting from Perl

Specifically on Windows, you could look at PowerShell that has a bit of a learning curve but is very powerful. You can see [the discussion on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676342/powershell-expensive-parsing) around it.

Also on Windows, there is a [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659) which is oldie but goodie and designed specifically for logs. [Hanselman's article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnalyzeYourWebServerDataAndBeEmpoweredWithLogParserAndLogParserLizardGUI.aspx) could be a good introduction.

Finally, if you need something with a lot more power for more permanent infrastructure, you could look at [LogStash](http://logstash.net/) and/or [Graylog](http://www.graylog2.org/). There is [an article explaining the setup for both](http://boojapathy.wordpress.com/2012/04/29/logstash-graylog-cant-ask-more-for-logging/).

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Python](http://python.org/), a powerful but unintimidating scripting language. It may be as simple for you as something like:

```
log = open("file.log")
for line in log:
    if "Error" in line:
        print line
```